# Batch insert: is there a way to just skip on next record when a constraint is violated?

Tags: oracle, mybatis

I am using mybatis to perform a massive batch insert on an oracle DB.

My process is very simple: I am taking records from a list of files and inserting them into a specific table after performing some checks on the data.

-Each file contains an average of 180.000 records and I can have more than one file.

-Some records can be present in more than one file.

-A record is identical to another one if EVERY column matches, in other words I cannot simply perform a check on a specific field. And I have defined a constraint in my DB which makes sure this condition is satisfied.

To put it simply I want to just ignore the constraint exception Oracle will give to me in case that constraint is violated.

Record is not present?-->insert

Record is already present?--> go ahead

is this possible with mybatis?Or can I accomplish something at DB level?

I have control on both Application Server and DB so please tell me what's the most efficient way to accomplish this task (even though I'd like to avoid being too much DB dependant...)

**of course, I'd like to avoid performing a select* before each insertion...given the number of records I am dealing with it would ruin my application's performances**

Comment: I suggest you investigate using a MERGE statement instead of an INSERT.

Comment: Mmm...yes it could work but I am afraid that, even though merge would be more efficient than calling a select, it would still be less efficient than just skipping the constraint exception. In the end even if I notice I am trying to insert an already existing record I wouldn't perform any operation (like an update or so) on it, which is actually what merge is for.

Comment: You don't have to do an update; just don't use a `when matched` clause. Are you only expecting duplicates to already exist in the table, or could you have duplicates within a batch?

Comment: Just in the table..yes I'll try today and let you know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#CHDEGDDG) hint:

```
insert /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(table_name index_name) */
into table_name
select * ...
```

Comment: Seems like what I am searching for as long as for Oracle this isn't just an "hint" but a "direction"! Can you explain me better this sentence, please? "When a unique key violation is encountered, a row-level rollback occurs and execution resumes with the next input row". What row level rollaback actually means?

Comment: @Phate Yes, this is a directive and not a hint (I wish they didn't call them hints, it's very misleading).  Normally, when there's an error the entire statement is rolled back, but in this case only the relevant rows are (silently) rolled back.

Comment: Thanks, it's just what I wanted :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about JDBC, but at least in OCI it is possible. With batch operations you pass vectors as bind variables and you also get back vector(s) of returned IDs and also a vector of error codes.

- You can also use MERGE on database server side together with custon collection types. Something like:

  `merge into t`

  `using ( select * from TABLE(:var) v)`

  `on ( v.id = t.id )`

  `when not matched then insert ...`

Where :var is bind variable of SQL type: `TABLE OF <recordname>`
The word `"TABLE"` is a construct used to cast from bind variable into a table.

- Another option is to use SQL error loggin clause:

  `DBMS_ERRLOG.create_error_log (dml_table_name => 't');`

  `insert into t(...) values(...) log errors reject limit unlimited;`

Then after the load you will have to truncate error loging table err$_t;

- another option would be to use [external tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm)

It looks that any solution is quite a lot work to do, when compared to using sqlldr.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore error with error table

```
insert 
into table_name
select * 
from selected_table
LOG ERRORS INTO SANJI.ERROR_LOG('some comment' ) 
                    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

and error table schema is :

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY  TABLE SANJI.ERROR_LOG (
        ora_err_number$         number,
        ora_err_mesg$           varchar2(2000),
        ora_err_rowid$          rowid,
        ora_err_optyp$          varchar2(2),
        ora_err_tag$            varchar2(2000),
        n1                      varchar2(128)
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```